# How to write and read a file with forking in C

Tags: c, linux, file, fork, flock

i'm wondering how can we write and read in a multiprocess program written in C? I tried using flock and file descriptors but it didn't work. Is there anyone to help me? Thanks.

```
            int f;        
            f = open("test.txt",O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_SYNC | O_APPEND);
            int lock = flock(f, LOCK_SH);
            write(f, "asdfg", sizeof("asdfg"));
            int release = flock(f, LOCK_UN);
            close(f);
```

Comment: If you tried, that's great, but what's important when asking a question here is you **show us what you tried**. Quite often you're closer to the solution than you realize and we can push it over the finish line with a little edit. Asking us to guess what you've done and write code from scratch is not constructive use of anyone's time.

Comment: I edited and added locking and writing part

Comment: you do not need locks if a process exclusively opens, writes and closes files. What does your fork do here? why do you use a shared lock?

Comment: Saying "it didn't work" is not really a helpful description of the problem. How did you test it and what results did you get that lead you to conclude that it didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

[`flock`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) does not necessarily prevent your process from writing to a file, it's just a tool to coordinate between different processes and threads. As in the documentation:

> `flock()` places advisory locks only; given suitable permissions on a file a process is free to ignore the use of `flock()` and perform I/O on the file.

You're using a shared lock here (`LOCK_SH`) which means more than one thread can use it. Sounds like you need an exclusive lock if you want one thread to wait until the other is done.

If you want to have exclusive write access, you should use `LOCK_EX`. You should also **pay close attention to the return value** as ignoring this leads to all sorts of trouble. Assuming something succeeded, and then proceeding, invites lots of difficult to fix bugs.